# copies of events appearing continually

Tags: civievent

Civi 4.6.10 Joomla 3.4.5

Our events after being created at some pointed are being copied by the system.  Note the following id numbers as well.  Original event was 4352.

LILA TEST RECORD  (ID: 4352)

Copy of LILA TEST RECORD  (ID: 4370)

Copy of LILA TEST RECORD  (ID: 4420)

Copy of LILA TEST RECORD  (ID: 4470)

This happened to us in the old version.  I have over 451 event copies to delete now.

here is another sample it even went back to 2012:

Copy of Advanced Air Sealing  (ID: 3871)
Smyrna  New York    Advanced Air Sealing    No  Aug 07, 2012 8:00 AM        Yes

Copy of Copy of Advanced Air Sealing  (ID: 4217)
Smyrna  New York    Advanced Air Sealing    No  Aug 07, 2012 8:00 AM        Yes

Copy of Advanced Air Sealing  (ID: 4218)
Smyrna  New York    Advanced Air Sealing    No  Aug 07, 2012 8:00 AM        Yes

Copy of Copy of Advanced Air Sealing  (ID: 4219)
Smyrna  New York    Advanced Air Sealing    No  Aug 07, 2012 8:00 AM        Yes

Copy of Advanced Air Sealing  (ID: 4022)
Smyrna  New York    Advanced Air Sealing    No  Aug 07, 2012 8:00 AM        Yes

Copy of Copy of Advanced Air Sealing  (ID: 4562)
Smyrna  New York    Advanced Air Sealing    No  Aug 07, 2012 8:00 AM        Yes

Copy of Advanced Air Sealing  (ID: 4563)
Smyrna  New York    Advanced Air Sealing    No  Aug 07, 2012 8:00 AM        Yes

Copy of Copy of Copy of Advanced Air Sealing  (ID: 4564)
Smyrna  New York    Advanced Air Sealing    No  Aug 07, 2012 8:00 AM        Yes

Copy of Copy of Advanced Air Sealing  (ID: 4565)
Smyrna  New York    Advanced Air Sealing    No  Aug 07, 2012 8:00 AM        Yes

Copy of Copy of Copy of Advanced Air Sealing  (ID: 4566)
Smyrna  New York    Advanced Air Sealing    No  Aug 07, 2012 8:00 AM        Yes

Copy of Copy of Advanced Air Sealing  (ID: 4567)
Smyrna  New York    Advanced Air Sealing    No  Aug 07, 2012 8:00 AM        Yes

Copy of Copy of Advanced Air Sealing  (ID: 4568)
Smyrna  New York    Advanced Air Sealing    No  Aug 07, 2012 8:00 AM        Yes

Copy of Advanced Air Sealing  (ID: 4332)
Smyrna  New York    Advanced Air Sealing    No  Aug 07, 2012 8:00 AM        Yes

again note the ID numbers....

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't feels like a CiviCRM Core problem to me but I don't know what else it could be either.

The "Copy of" seems to indicate that it use the CRM_Event_BAO_Event::copy as if used by the Copy action in manage event page.

You may check for any custom code that could contains `CRM_Event_BAO_Event::copy` or something like that.

You could also try to disable CiviCRM extensions or Joomla extensions one by one and see if it keeps happening

Comment: where do I find the custom code?

Comment: Not sure for joomla extensions/plugins but for CiviCRM, you should look in https://yoursite.org/civicrm/admin/setting/path?reset=1 - Custom PHP Path Directory and CiviCRM Extensions Directory

Comment: can I send you the event.php?

Comment: @http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/72/samuelsov
can I send you the copy section nothing as noted above with BAO...but maybe I can remove the whole event copy thing?

Comment: can I send you the copy section nothing as noted above with BAO...but maybe I can remove the whole event copy thing?

Comment: i don't know what you want to remove but if it's in the civicrm core code, please don't... if it's a custom module or extension, i might have a look, please create an account on https://chat.civicrm.org and we could talk a bit more about it

Comment: @civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/72/samuelsovjust found this:

if ($newEvent && is_a($newEvent, 'CRM_Event_DAO_Event')) {
      $copyEvent = $newEvent;